# multiple pivot on dynamic columns

Tags: pivot

I have some transaction data that I need to present on a monthly basis, as the transaction list grows every month. Here is the sample data.

[image]

and hopefully, it could be presented something like this.
[image]

it's a bit complicated (at least for me) than the other sample I found and tried ...

Comment: better provide data as text format

Comment: sorry.. I tried but it says I need some reputation point (10) before I make the changed. and I'm new on this. thanks.